# React ref attribute access with name string that needed to be concatenated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, concatenation

In React/javascript, there is a map function like this

```
{this.state.caseDetails.plaintiff.map((p, i)=>{
  return(
    <div className={`col-lg-${inputWidth}`}>
      <input type="hidden" ref={'plaintiff_id_' + i} value={p.id} />
      <input type='text' ref={'plaintiff_name_' + i} className='form-control' defaultValue={p.name}/>
    </div>
  )
})}
```

I created the attributes as above plaintiff_id_0 up to the size of array by concatenate the i variable. However, the problem now is that i would like to get the value of those data using *ref*, So i created a for loop like this:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < this.state.caseDetails.plaintiff.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.refs.("plaintiff_id_".concat(i)).value);
      //Tried this.refs.("plaintiff_id_"+i).value etc.
}
```

And also different kind of version to concat i to the string, but it keeps telling me that this is a syntax error, is there anyway to access these ref as i want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < this.state.caseDetails.plaintiff.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.refs["plaintiff_id_".concat(i)].value);
  //OR
      console.log(this.refs["plaintiff_id_" + i].value);
}
```

Comment: Pick this as answer as it solved it clean and clearly and the fastest response.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bracket notation and do: `this.refs['plaintiff_id_' + i]`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the DOM element using refs as follows:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < this.state.caseDetails.plaintiff.length; i++) {

  var plaintiffIdRef = "plaintiff_id_" + i;
  console.log(React.findDOMNode(this.refs[plaintiffIdRed]).value)

  var plaintiffNameRef = "plaintiff_name_" + i;
  console.log(React.findDOMNode(this.refs[plaintiffNameRef]).value)

}
```